# Python group the data by time (number of seconds) & plot graph

Tags: python

I have a dataset of 'Volume' and 'price' of trades from 11am to 3pm over 30 days, and I want to average the data and group them by time. 
[image]

my code is:`df = Trade.groupby([Trade["Time"].dt.hour, Trade["Time"].dt.minute, Trade["Time"].dt.second]).mean()`

and this gives me:[image]

EDIT: Instead of group by 'hour''minute' and 'second', how can I group them together as one column instead of having three columns of 'time'?
However, how can I plot 'Time' against 'Volume' in this case? do I need to convert time to the number of seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you use seconds for time, and I would use a moving average. Google 'Simple moving Average' and 'Exponential Moving Average'.

[Moving Averages](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:moving_averages)

Good luck, hope I helped :D